# How to validate a form field based on the data from another one? - Laravel 6

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I have a form which contains the following fields:

- n_census (provides information about the total population from a town or city)
- n_participants (provides information about the number of participants in an election process according to n_census)

I would like to validate n_participants according to n_census because it's not possible to have more n_participants than n_census.

The code I use to validate both fields (and others I have but not relevant for this issue) is:

```php
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    $customMessages = [
        'required' => ':attribute es obligatori',
        'min' => ':attribute cal que siga, com a mínim, :min caracters',
        'max' => ':attribute cal que siga, com a màxim, :max caracters',
        'string' => ':attribute cal que siga una cadena de caracters',
        'int' => ':attribute cal que siga un enter',
        'email' => ':attribute es un email',
        'confirmed' => 'No has confirmat el correu electrònic'
    ];

    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
        'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        'dni' => ['required', 'string', 'min:9', 'max:9'],
        'surname1' => ['required', 'string', 'max:50'],
        'surname2' => ['required', 'string', 'max:50'],
        'v1' => ['required', 'string', 'max: 100'],
        'v2' => ['required', 'string', 'max: 100'],
        'district' => ['required', 'int'],
        'section' => ['required', 'int'],
        'chair' => ['required', 'string'],
        'municipality' => ['required'],
        'province' => ['required'],
        'n_census' => ['required', 'int'],
        'n_participants' => ['required', 'int', 'max: 50']
    ], $customMessages);
}
```

Is it possible to use `Validator::make()` to do that?

Comment: checkout this https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#conditionally-adding-rules

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

```php
return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
            'dni' => ['required', 'string', 'min:9', 'max:9'],
            'surname1' => ['required', 'string', 'max:50'],
            'surname2' => ['required', 'string', 'max:50'],
            'v1' => ['required', 'string', 'max: 100'],
            'v2' => ['required', 'string', 'max: 100'],
            'district' => ['required', 'int'],
            'section' => ['required', 'int'],
            'chair' => ['required', 'string'],
            'municipality' =>  ['required'],
            'province' =>  ['required'],
            'n_participants' => ['required', 'int', 'max: 50'],
            'n_census' => ['required', 'int','gte:n_participants'],
        ], $customMessages);
```

added **gte:n_participants** in condtion 
https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#rule-gt